# How do I prevent a request from being identified as unauthorized?

Tags: angular

I try to prevent a request to a specific url from being intercepted by the authorization service that checks the 401 status but for some reason this request is always intercepted and discarded as unauthorized. There are other interceptors but they do not do any authorization verification

Here I verify the url and if it matches the one of my interest I try to simply pass the request through

```
if (request.url === 'some/api/news-letter') {
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

How do I prevent a request from being identified as unauthorized?

Thanks in advance

Here is the interceptor code

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthExpiredInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private loginModalService: LoginModalService,
        private accountService: AccountService,
        private router: Router,
        private loginService: LoginService
    ) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (request.url === 'some/api/news-letter') {
            return next.handle(request);
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
                (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {},
                (err: any) => {
                    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (err.status === 401) {
                            if (this.accountService.isAuthenticated()) {
                                this.accountService.authenticate(null);
                                this.loginModalService.open();
                            } else {
                                this.loginService.logout();
                                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to cancel the http request for a specific URL if the end user session got expired or if he is not authorized to access that URL. Best way to cancel a request is mentioned below,

```
    import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
    
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {
      if (request.url === 'some/api/news-letter') {
          if (//.... logic to check if end user is authorized) {
              return next.handle(request);
           } else {
              this.loginService.logout();
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
              return EMPTY;
           }
      }
      return next.handle(request);
    }
```

Comment: I am not trying to cancel the request, but if the request comes from a specific url pass the authorization check bypass